# How to write a Text to a Text File in C# on Android

Tags: c#, android, file, streamreader, streamwriter

I want to write a code in C# that reads a text file in Android and if it doesn't exist, create it. I want my application to read the same file everytime I run my App and create that file the first time I open my app.I wrote this code but it doesn't work.It only creates a directory if it doesn't exist but it doesn't create my text file.Thank you for your answer in advance.

```
network=Network.Main;
        
        
        
        //string _fileName = Path.Combine(, "bitcoinwallets.phoenixbtcwallet");
        string rootPath = Android.App.Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir(null).ToString();

        var filePathDir = Path.Combine(rootPath, "PhoenixWallet/");

        if (!File.Exists(filePathDir))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(filePathDir);
        }
        bitcoinPrivateKeysFile= filePathDir+"bitcoinwallets.phoenixbtcwallet";
        
        string bitcoinprivateKeyItem;
        
        if(File.Exists( bitcoinPrivateKeysFile))
        {
        StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(bitcoinPrivateKeysFile);
        
        while (!sr.EndOfStream ){
            
            bitcoinprivateKeyItem=sr.ReadLine();
            bitcoinprivKeys.Add(bitcoinprivateKeyItem);
            
        }
        Console.WriteLine("File Exists");
        sr.Close();
        } else {
            
            Key bitcoinKey = new Key();
            
            BitcoinSecret bitcoinsecret = new BitcoinSecret(bitcoinKey,network);
            
            StreamWriter sw;
            sw= File.CreateText(bitcoinPrivateKeysFile);
            sw.WriteLine(bitcoinsecret.PrivateKey);
            Console.WriteLine("File Does not Exist");
            sw.Close();
        }
        
        
        
        btn.Text = "New Wallet";
        
        bitcoinWalletAddressTextView.Text=bitcoinprivKeys[0];
```

Comment: It's seems you are missing the code for creating the Text File if it doesn't exists.

Comment: And for Directorys there is Directory.Exists.

Comment: **bitcoinPrivateKeys**File= filePathDir+"bitcoinwallets.phoenixbtcwallet"; ... really??

Answer (score 0):

You are checking `File.Exists(...) != null` which is a bit nonsensical, since `File.Exists` returns a `bool` value which is never `null`.

So just do `if (File.Exists(...)) {...}`

```
if (File.Exists(...)) 
{
     // read file
}
else
{
    // create file
}
```

Comment: *but I still get the same error* - which error do you get?